# Boost Graph Library: How do I keep a permanant reference to a vertex? (i.e. not subject to vertex re-numbering)

Tags: c++, boost, graph

Let's say, I want to keep a reference to a vertex. E.g. in a finite state machine, I want to tag the start state and the final state(s). The first thing that came to mind is Graph:vertex_descriptor. However, it's an unsigned int and if a vertex is removed from the graph, the remaining vertices could be renumbered.

So what's a good way to keep a reference of a vertex that is not subject to vertex removal (of course except if the referenced vertex itself is removed). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the table "Summary of Descriptor and Iterator Invalidation." on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html), you will see that vertex descriptors are only invalidated during vertex removals if you use `vecS` as the `VertexList` template argument to `adjacency_list`. You you want vertex descriptors that never become invalidated (unless they are the ones being removed), you should use `listS` instead (or any other except `vecS`, although, for vertices, you're better just use `listS`).

Another possibility, that I have used in some cases, when applicable, is to place the two (start, final) vertices you don't want to be invalidated at the very start of the graph (the first two vertices you add to the graph). When you do that, even with `vecS`, the removal of vertices will not shift the position of the first vertices (only those after the removed vertex). However, this is a hack and you shouldn't really rely too much on this trick.

I have also implemented a replacement for the `adjacency_list` class which also includes an option for a pooled container that has most of the advantages of `vecS` (such as locality) but preserves vertex descriptors everywhere. You can [check it out](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/boost_graph_ext_mp/tree/master/trunk/boost/graph), but be warned that it is not quite production-ready yet.

As far as choosing which way to refer to the vertices.. that answer is always `vertex_descriptor`. Anything else is not really safe. Iterators are only for doing a traversal, not to be used as "pointers".

EDIT: If you need to test, in the context of a generic function, whether a particular Graph type has "persistent" vertex descriptors, I don't know that there is any direct test for that, but you can check the iterator-category on the vertex iterators. If the iterator-category is "random-access", then it most usually means that the vertex descriptors are not persistent (could be invalidated by removals). By iterator-category, I mean, from [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), getting the traits of `vertex_iterator`. I guess this is also a bit of a hack, but it's a fairly safe one.

Comment: Is it possible to use `boost::stable_vector<>` for now?

Comment: Thanks! The whole BGL thing is starting to make sense :)